# On the integration of piecewise linear functions over an edge

Tags: measure-theory, graph-theory

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an edge measure, and function $f$ be edgewise linear, i.e., it is continuous and its restriction to edge interior is a linear function. Then, at the bottom of the page 7 of [this handout](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0408028.pdf), the author claims that, for an edge $e=(u,v)$, we have

$$\int_{e}f\mathrm{d}\mathcal{E} = [f(u)+f(v)]\frac{\mathcal{E}(e)}{2}.$$

However, I don't understand where that factor $2$ in the RHS comes from. In particular, let's divide $e$ into $n$ segments. Thus we have

$$\int_{e}f \mathrm{d}\mathcal{E} = \sum_{i}f_{i}\mathrm{d}\mathcal{E}_{i}$$

$\mathcal{E}$ is distributed evenly among all segments. Moreover, $f$ is defined over vertices, meaning it is nontrivial only for the first and the last segment. So, we have

$$\int_{e}f \mathrm{d}\mathcal{E} = \sum_{i}f_{i}\mathrm{d}\mathcal{E}_{i} = \frac{\mathcal{E}}{n}\sum_{i}f_{i} = \frac{\mathcal{E}}{n}[f(u)+f(v)]$$

Is my derivation wrong or the handout's claim is problematic?

Comment: What do you mean by "it" and "nontrivial," in saying "it is nontrivial only for the first and last segment"?  Isn't $f$ linear (maybe a better word would be 'affine,' but that's not what the authors use) on the whole edge?

Comment: @leslietownes: (i) We have $n$ segments identified by indices $\{1, \cdots, n\}$. $u$ (resp., $v$) belongs to segment $1$ (resp., $n$). So, $f_{1} = f(u)\neq 0$ and  $f_{n}=f(v)\neq 0$ (non-triviality). However, $(\forall j\in \{2, \cdots, n-1\}) f_{j} = 0$ (triviality). (ii) Yes, as stated in the question, $f$ is piecewise linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're looking at just a single edge, then this is equivalent to the statement about integrating a linear function over a closed interval:
$$
   \int_{x=a}^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx = [f(a) + f(b)] \cdot \frac{b-a}{2}.
$$
We can show that this is correct in general by writing $f(x) = px + q$, evaluating $\left.\frac12px^2 + qx\right|_{x=a}^b$, and comparing to the right-hand side. Some motivation for writing the right-hand side in this way comes from thinking of the integral as the area under $f(x)$. Assuming $f$ is positive on $[a,b]$, this region is a trapezoid with opposite parallel sides of length $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, separated by a distance of $b-a$.

It's fine to switch to the one-variable integral, because on any edge $e$, the edge measure $\mathcal E$ is equal to Lebesgue measure up to a constant factor. Howeve, to take that constant factor into account, we should replace $b-a$ (the Lebesgue measure of $[a,b]$) by $\mathcal E(e)$, which gives us the formula in question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we relax the linearity assumption, can one still evaluate the integral $\int_{e}f\mathrm{d}\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: If we relax the linearity assumption, then it's still true that the integral $\int_e f\,\mathrm d\mathcal E$ is equivalent to integrating a one-variable function over a closed interval, but for an arbitrary function, we can't in general replace that integral by an evaluation of $f$.